# Apache HTTP Server 2.4.41 is confusingly serving virtual host pages

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

My `httpd-vhosts.conf` looks  like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/rodde.net"
    ServerName rodde.net
    ServerAlias www.rodde.net
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/coderodde.net"
    ServerName coderodde.net
    ServerAlias wwww.coderodde.net
</VirtualHost>
```

My `C:Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` contains:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 www.coderodde.net
127.0.0.1 www.rodde.net
127.0.0.1 rodde.net
127.0.0.1 coderodde.net
```

My `C:\Apache24\htdocs\rodde.net\index.html` contains:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>
rodde.net works!
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

My `C:/Apache24/htdocs/coderodde.net/index.html` contains:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>
coderodde.net works!
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

My `C:/Apache24/htdocs/index.html` contains:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Apache HTTP Server 2.4.41 works!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, `httpd.exe -S`:

```
C:\Apache24\bin>httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server rodde.net (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:23)
         port 80 namevhost rodde.net (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:23)
                 alias www.rodde.net
         port 80 namevhost coderodde.net (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:29)
                 alias wwww.coderodde.net
ServerRoot: "C:/Apache24"
Main DocumentRoot: "C:/Apache24/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "C:/Apache24/logs/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="C:/Apache24/logs/" mechanism=default
PidFile: "C:/Apache24/logs/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
Define: SRVROOT=c:/Apache24
```

My problem is this: '

1. When I visit `rodde.net`or `www.rodde.net`, I see the text **rodde.net works!**, as I should.
2. When I visit `coderodde.net`, I see the text **coderodde.net works!**, as I should.
3. ***However***, when I visit `www.coderodde.net` or `localhost`, I see the text **rodde.net works!**.

Comment: Are you sure your main httpd config file is set to look for vhosts in a separate file? I have to add this IncludeOptional conf/vhosts/*.conf

Comment: I use a single `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> default server rodde.net (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:23)
> ```

This is your default server i.e. the default virtual host. It is used every time there's no matching explicit `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`. That's the case when you visit e.g. `http://localhost`.

> ```
> port 80 namevhost coderodde.net (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:29)
>         alias wwww.coderodde.net
> ```

This virtual host has two names: `coderodde.net` and `wwww.coderodde.net`, with **four w**'s. That's why it won't match `www.coderodde.net` with three w's, and the default virtual host is used, instead. That's called a *typo*.

Comment: Kiitos paljon, kamu!